# PowerShell Where-Object - How to group conditions

Tags: powershell, where-clause

I have a PowerShell script with a variable that is piped into "where-object". This where clause contains multiple statements that have to be true (-AND) and two statements, where at least one has to be true (-XOR). How do I group them? Nothing I've tried worked so far:

```
$var | Where-Object { condition1 -AND condition2 -AND condition3 -XOR condition4 }
$var | Where-Object { condition1 -AND condition2 -AND (condition3 -XOR  condition4) }    
$var | Where-Object { (condition1 -AND condition2) -AND condition3 -XOR  condition4 }
$var | Where-Object { (condition1 -AND condition2) -AND (condition3 -XOR condition4) }
```

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The 4th one looks correct but it's hard to tell with such a trivial example. `($true -and $true) -and ($false -xor $true)` returns `True`. Are you not able to show the data you're working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the suggestions and possibilities to check the outcome of the conditions. In the end I've used a slightly different solution:

```
if ( $var | Where-Object { condition1 -AND condition2 -AND condition3 } ) {
    Write-Host "Do some stuff"
    }
else {
    if ( $var | Where-Object { condition1 -AND condition2 -AND condition4 } ) {
        Write-Host "Do other stuff"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this one :

```
$var | Where-Object { condition1 -AND condition2 -AND (condition3 -OR  condition4) }
```

As a side reminder, here's the [Microsoft official man page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847789.aspx) that can interest you :

```
    -or       Logical or. TRUE when either     (1 -eq 1) -or (1 -eq 2) 
              or both statements are TRUE.     True


    -xor      Logical exclusive or. TRUE       (1 -eq 1) -xor (2 -eq 2)
              only when one of the statements  False 
              is TRUE and the other is FALSE.
```

And since I'm here, another tought :
Depending on the size and structure of your $var object, checking ALL conditions on ALL Objects can take some time, you should filter it :

Reminder : **?** is a natural alias to **Where-Object** :

```
$var | ? { condition1 } |? { condition2 } |? { condition3 -OR  condition4 }
```

This might help your script to go faster ...

Comment: Your recommended solution is actually less efficient because it involves more piping and repeated calls to `Where-Object`.  The `-and` and `-or` operators in PowerShell use [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) to only evaluate as many operands as necessary to determine a result.  They will not "check all conditions on all objects" unless they need to.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip, and for the teaching about short-circuiting iCodez ! :)